# How To Handle Tag Overlap?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been wondering about tag overlap lately. For example:

- Every `soql` post is about `query`, but not the other way around
- Every `formula-field` post is about `formula`, but not the other way around
- Every `before-trigger` question is about `trigger` *and* `apex`.

Should we retag new questions when we see a gap there? Surely tag synonyms are inappropriate here, but I'm wondering if it really makes sense to add the `query` tag to `soql` posts, and so on.

I'm not sure how much tagging matters to others here, but I know I find it makes the search process easier.

Comment: I have been trying to make tagging more accurate when editing as I do like it for searching, though more of that is getting rid of incorrectly applied tags of which 'salesforce-community' seems to be the most common.

Comment: Heh, might even see a larger variety of tag badges awarded if the correct ones were applied to posts too, not to mention the effect it would have on making more specific searches fruitful! :)

Comment: My favorite tage to remove lately that was added by others who were not the OP is "error". Seems to be a pattern lately of tags being added to questions that add no value is classifying the question. Lots of tags that are way to general in general

Comment: @Eric I have noticed one user in particular making a massive amount of such edits. I've started rejecting more of them.

Comment: @Eric I have been rejecting that users edits with the error tag on them or removing error when the other changes are acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

It's going to depend a lot on the context I think. You state correctly that every `soql` post is about a `query` but not the other way around, but there are definitely cases where one would be appropriate over the other, for instance if you didn't know whether to use SOSL or SOQL you might want to use query.

IMO `Formula` could apply to Visualforce function formulae as much as formula fields, and `trigger` and `apex` definitely deserve to be separate, and `before-trigger` carries some context that neither of the others do on their own.

The first two cases I presented are definitely close to being edge cases, and I think `query` and `formula` could be made redundant and replaced with the more specific varieties: a question about what is best between SOQL and SOSL could simply use both and probably reach a wider audience than `query` ever would.